# Avoiding deletion with LRU in session memcache handler

Tags: php, database, session, web-applications, memcached

I have configured my session save handler to work with memcache instead of file based because it caused a lock while having more than one open tab. I've done this in php.ini (`session.save_handler = memcache`)

Because my memcache is full, I believe these items are being deleted through the LRU algorithm. How do u suggest to overcome this? Is there any simple save-to-disk option, or `set` to memcache to not delete these unless expired?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, memcached will delete items in order to be able to store new ones. And it has no mechanism to persist items. You can set it to not delete items unless expired, but if you do that and the cache fills up with unexpired items, then it will not accept any new items, which means that no-one will be able to start a new session (or modify an existing one).

Bottom line: mem**cache**d is a cache, not a database. Use it only to store data you can recreate when needed. (Also, see the memcached FAQ entry [Everyone does it!](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#Why_is_memcached_not_recommended_for_sessions?_Everyone_does_it!).)

The amount of memory that memcached can use is set when the memcached server starts up. You could arrange for it to use more memory, if you have more memory on the server, in which case it will probably keep sessions around for longer. But that's just delaying the inevitable. (Also, as the article linked to from that FAQ entry points out, since memcached is not in any way failure resistant, you cannot restart the memcached server without losing *all* of your saved sessions.)

Comment: How would you recommend handling saving sessions? As I mentioned, I had a problem using the file save handler, which locked the file, and multiple tabs hanged each other.

Comment: @Noam: I think you should focus on the issue causing tabbed sessions to hold the session lock for too long. Perhaps you need to explicitly end the session. I'm afraid I don't really know a lot about PHP sessions, but my guess is that if you're experiencing locking problems, then no session save handler will help (either the tabs will lock or the sessions will get corrupted.) Perhaps you should try asking a specific question about your specific problem with sessions and tabs, rather than assume that the solution is to change session save handlers.